# Sum date with a varchar field

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored proc. In the stored proc i have a date field and a varchar field. How can I do to sum date with varchar? The varchar fiel accept only numeric value, example:
'1', '2', '60' and so on. This field do not accept word, only digit.

Below the stored proc code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TS_ODO.odo_prs_registra_pedido_exclu(p_msg_xml     in clob,
                                                                 p_cod_retorno out number,
                                                                 p_msg_retorno out varchar2,
                                                                 p_versao      in varchar2 default 'N') is
  ----- variaveis auxiliares
  v_posicao number;
  --
  v_doc         xmldom.DOMDocument;
  v_cod_retorno number;
  v_msg_retorno varchar2(4000);
  --
  v_usuario                ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.cod_usuario_atu%type;
  v_cod_operadora          ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.cod_operadora%type;
  v_cod_prestador_ts       ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.cod_prestador_ts%type;
  v_cod_motivo_exclusao    ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.cod_motivo_exclusao%type;
  v_data_exclusao          ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.dat_exclusao%type;
  v_data_realizacao        ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.dat_exclusao%type;
  v_data_apresentacao      ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.dat_exclusao%type;
  v_data_representacao     ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.dat_exclusao%type;
  v_data_direcionamento    ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.dat_exclusao%type;
  v_data_notificacao_exc   ts_odo.odo_prestador_substituto.dt_notif_voluntaria%type;
  v_txt_exclusao           ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.txt_exclusao%type;
  v_ind_situacao           ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.ind_situacao%type;
  v_cod_prestador_ts_subst ts_odo.odo_prestador_substituto.cod_prestador_ts_substituto%type;
  v_cod_rede               ts_odo.odo_prestador_substituto.cod_rede_excluido%type;
  v_dt_fim_hab_aux         ts_odo.odo_rede_prestador.dt_exclusao%type;
  v_dt_ini_hab_aux         ts_odo.odo_rede_prestador.dt_ini_hab%type;

  --v_prazo_subs_ans         ts_odo.odo_controle_sistema.val_parametro%type;

  --
  v_ind_rede_habilitaca varchar2(1);
  v_qtd_redes           number;
  v_existe              number;
  v_exclusao_voluntaria varchar2(1);
  v_ind_lista_negra     varchar2(1);
  vTxtObs               clob;
  --
  vNomeOperadora        ts.operadora.nom_operadora%type;
  vSubstitutos          varchar2(1000);
  vCodPrestadorSubst    ts_odo.odo_prestador_servico.cod_prestador%type;
  vExisteSubstituto     number;
  vTrocaPrestSubstituto varchar2(1000);
  vTrocaSubstituidoPor  varchar2(1000);
  vSituacaoOperadora    ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.ind_situacao%type;
  --

  V_IND_LEI13003  varchar2(2);
  V_IND_EXCLUSAO_VOLUNTARIA varchar2(2);


  function verificaRedeHab(pCodRede        in number,
                           pCodPrestadorTs in number,
                           pCodOperadora   in varchar2) return varchar2 is
    v_hab varchar2(1);
  begin
    --
    select decode(count(1), 0, 'N', 'S')
      into v_hab
      from ts_odo.odo_rede_prestador rpr
     where rpr.cod_prestador_ts = pCodPrestadorTs
       and rpr.cod_rede = pCodRede
       and rpr.cod_operadora = pCodOperadora
       and rpr.dt_exclusao is null;
    --
    return v_hab;
    --
  exception
    when others then
      return 'N';
  end;
  --
begin
  --
  v_posicao := 1;
  --
  if nvl(p_versao, 'N') = 'S' then
    p_cod_retorno := 0;
    p_msg_retorno := 'versao 1.14';
    return;
  end if;
  --
  v_posicao := 2;
  --
  ts_cria_doc_xml(p_msg_xml, v_doc, v_cod_retorno, v_msg_retorno);
  --
  if v_cod_retorno <> 0 then
    p_cod_retorno := v_cod_retorno;
    p_msg_retorno := 'prs_registra_pedido_exclusao - ' || v_posicao || ': ' || v_msg_retorno;
    return;
  end if;
  --
  v_posicao             := 3;
  v_cod_prestador_ts    := ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','COD_PRESTADOR_TS');
  v_usuario             := ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','USUARIO');
  v_cod_motivo_exclusao := ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','COD_MOTIVO_EXCLUSAO');
  v_txt_exclusao        := ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','TXT_EXCLUSAO');
  v_cod_operadora       := ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','COD_OPERADORA');
  --
  ts_client_info(v_usuario, '');
  --
  v_posicao := 8;
  --
  if v_cod_prestador_ts is null then
    p_cod_retorno := 1;
        p_msg_retorno := 'Prestador não informado';
    return;
  end if;
  --
  if v_cod_operadora is null then
    p_cod_retorno := 1;
    p_msg_retorno := 'Operadora não informada';
    return;
  end if;
  --
  if v_cod_motivo_exclusao is null then
    --
    p_cod_retorno := 1;
    p_msg_retorno := 'Motivo da exclusão não informado.';
    return;
  end if;
  --
  begin
    v_data_exclusao := to_date(ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','DATA_EXCLUSAO'),'dd/mm/yyyy');
  exception
    when others then
      p_cod_retorno := 1;
      p_msg_retorno := 'Data exclusão inválida.';
      return;
  end;
  --
  if v_data_exclusao is null then
    p_cod_retorno := 1;
    p_msg_retorno := 'Data exclusão não informada. ';
    return;
  end if;
  --
  begin
    v_data_realizacao := to_date(ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','DATA_REALIZACAO'),'dd/mm/yyyy');
  exception
    when others then
      p_cod_retorno := 1;
      p_msg_retorno := 'Data realização inválida. ';
      return;
  end;
  --
  if v_data_realizacao is null then
    p_cod_retorno := 1;
    p_msg_retorno := 'Data realização não informada. ';
    return;
  end if;
  --
  begin
    v_data_apresentacao := to_date(ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','DATA_APRESENTACAO'),'dd/mm/yyyy');
  exception
    when others then
      p_cod_retorno := 1;
      p_msg_retorno := 'Data apresentação inválida. ';
      return;
  end;
  --
  if v_data_apresentacao is null then
    p_cod_retorno := 1;
    p_msg_retorno := 'Data apresentação não informada. ';
    return;
  end if;
  --
  begin
    v_data_representacao := to_date(ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','DATA_REPRESENTACAO'),'dd/mm/yyyy');
  exception
    when others then
      p_cod_retorno := 1;
      p_msg_retorno := 'Data representação inválida. ';
      return;
  end;
  --
  if v_data_representacao is null then
    p_cod_retorno := 1;
    p_msg_retorno := 'Data representação não informada. ';
    return;
  end if;
  --
  select ind_situacao
    into vSituacaoOperadora
    from ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora
   where cod_prestador_ts = v_cod_prestador_ts
     and cod_operadora    = v_cod_operadora;
  --
  if vSituacaoOperadora != 'E' then
      if v_data_exclusao < trunc(sysdate) then
        p_cod_retorno := 1;
        p_msg_retorno := 'Data exclusão não pode ser menor que a data atual. ';
        return;
      end if;
  end if;
  --
  begin
    v_data_notificacao_exc := to_date(ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','DATA_NOTIFICACAO_EXC'),'dd/mm/yyyy');
  exception
    when others then
      p_cod_retorno := 1;
      p_msg_retorno := 'Data de Notificação de exclusão inválida. ';
      return;
  end;
  --
  v_qtd_redes  := nvl(ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR','QTD_REDES'),0);
  vSubstitutos := null;
  vTrocaPrestSubstituto := null;
  vTrocaSubstituidoPor  := null;
  --
  v_posicao := 17;
  --
  for x in 1 .. v_qtd_redes loop
    --
    v_posicao := 18.1;
    v_cod_rede := ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR/REDE_EXCLUSAO','COD_REDE_' || x);
    v_posicao := 19;
    v_cod_prestador_ts_subst := ts_obtem_dados_xml(v_doc,'EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR/REDE_EXCLUSAO','COD_PRESTADOR_SUBST_' || x);
    v_posicao := 20;
    --
    if v_cod_rede is null then
      p_cod_retorno := 1;
      p_msg_retorno := 'Rede não informada.';
      rollback;
      return;
    end if;
    --
    v_posicao := 27;
    --
    select count(*)
      into v_existe
      from ts_odo.odo_motivo_exclusao_prestador
     where cod_motivo_exclusao = v_cod_motivo_exclusao
       and nvl(IND_EXCLUSAO_VOLUNTARIA, 'N') = 'S';
    --
    if v_existe <> 0 then
      v_exclusao_voluntaria := 'S';
    else
      v_exclusao_voluntaria := 'N';
    end if;
    --
    v_posicao := 23;
    --
    v_dt_fim_hab_aux := null;
    v_dt_ini_hab_aux := null;
    --
    begin
      select dt_exclusao, DT_INI_HAB
        into v_dt_fim_hab_aux, v_dt_ini_hab_aux
        from ts_odo.odo_rede_prestador
       where cod_prestador_ts = v_cod_prestador_ts_subst
         and cod_operadora    = v_cod_operadora
         and cod_rede         = v_cod_rede;
    exception
      when others then
        v_dt_fim_hab_aux := null;
        v_dt_ini_hab_aux := null;
    end;
    --
    v_posicao := 24;
    --
    update ts_odo.odo_rede_prestador
       set dt_exclusao     = v_data_exclusao,
           cod_usuario_atu = v_usuario,
           dt_atu          = sysdate
     where cod_prestador_ts = v_cod_prestador_ts
       and cod_operadora    = v_cod_operadora
       and cod_rede         = v_cod_rede;
    --
    v_posicao := 55;
    --
    update ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora
       set dat_exclusao      = v_data_exclusao,
           dt_limite_atd     = v_data_realizacao,
           dt_limite_remessa = v_data_apresentacao,
           dt_limite_recurso = v_data_representacao
     where cod_prestador_ts  = v_cod_prestador_ts
       and cod_operadora     = v_cod_operadora;
    --
    v_posicao := 25;
    --
    update ts_odo.odo_habilitacao_rede
       set data_fim_hab = v_data_exclusao
     where cod_prestador_ts     = v_cod_prestador_ts
       and cod_operadora        = v_cod_operadora
       and (trunc(data_fim_hab) = v_dt_fim_hab_aux or data_fim_hab is null);
    --
    v_posicao := 26;
    --
    update ts_odo.odo_habilitacao_exclusao_rede
       set dt_fim_exclusao = v_data_exclusao
     where cod_prestador_ts        = v_cod_prestador_ts
       and cod_operadora           = v_cod_operadora
       and (trunc(dt_fim_exclusao) = v_dt_fim_hab_aux or dt_fim_exclusao is null);
    --
    v_posicao := 28;
    --
    v_ind_rede_habilitaca := verificaRedeHab(v_cod_rede,
                                             v_cod_prestador_ts_subst,
                                             v_cod_operadora);
    --
    v_posicao := 29;
    --
    if v_cod_prestador_ts_subst is not null then
       --
       select cod_prestador
         into vCodPrestadorSubst
         from ts_odo.odo_prestador_servico
        where cod_prestador_ts = v_cod_prestador_ts_subst;
       --
       if vSubstitutos is null then
          vSubstitutos := vCodPrestadorSubst;
       else
          vSubstitutos := vSubstitutos || ' / ' || vCodPrestadorSubst;
       end if;
       --
    end if;
    --
    begin
      --
      ------  CL00539560#01

     SELECT  MEP.IND_LEI13003,MEP.IND_EXCLUSAO_VOLUNTARIA
     INTO V_IND_LEI13003, V_IND_EXCLUSAO_VOLUNTARIA
     FROM ODO_MOTIVO_EXCLUSAO_PRESTADOR MEP
     WHERE MEP.COD_MOTIVO_EXCLUSAO = v_cod_motivo_exclusao;

      if V_IND_LEI13003 = 'S' and V_IND_EXCLUSAO_VOLUNTARIA= 'S' then
      v_data_direcionamento := v_data_exclusao + 180;
      else
      v_data_direcionamento := sysdate -1;
       end if;
      ------  CL00539560#01
      --
      -- Verifica se já foi atribuido um substituto
      select nvl(count(1),0)
        into vExisteSubstituto
        from ts_odo.odo_prestador_substituto sub
       where sub.cod_prestador_ts_excluido = v_cod_prestador_ts
         and sub.cod_operadora_excluido    = v_cod_operadora
         and sub.cod_rede_excluido         = v_cod_rede;
      --
      if vExisteSubstituto <= 0 then
         --
         insert into ts_odo.odo_prestador_substituto ps
            (cod_prestador_ts_excluido,
             cod_operadora_excluido,
             cod_rede_excluido,
             dt_exclusao,
             dt_notif_voluntaria,
             cod_prestador_ts_substituto,
             dt_inicio_rede_substituto,
             dt_fim_exibe_direcionamento,
             ind_voluntario,
             dt_inclusao,
             cod_usuario_inclusao)
          values
            (v_cod_prestador_ts,
             v_cod_operadora,
             v_cod_rede,
             v_data_exclusao,
             v_data_notificacao_exc, --data notificacao voluntaria
             v_cod_prestador_ts_subst,
             v_dt_ini_hab_aux, -- inicio rede substituto
             v_data_direcionamento,
             v_exclusao_voluntaria, -- ind voluntario
             sysdate, -- data inclusao
             v_usuario); -- codigo usuario inclusao
        --
      else
        -- Só atualiza e gera ocorrencia para troca de substituto
        if v_cod_prestador_ts_subst is not null then
           --
           update ts_odo.odo_prestador_substituto
              set dt_atu                      = sysdate
                 ,cod_usuario_atu             = v_usuario
                 ,cod_prestador_ts_substituto = v_cod_prestador_ts_subst
            where cod_prestador_ts_excluido   = v_cod_prestador_ts
              and cod_operadora_excluido      = v_cod_operadora
              and cod_rede_excluido           = v_cod_rede;
           --
           -- Select apenas para pegar o codigo do prestador para incluir na gravação da ocorrencia
           select cod_prestador
             into vCodPrestadorSubst
             from ts_odo.odo_prestador_servico
            where cod_prestador_ts = v_cod_prestador_ts;
           --
           if vTrocaPrestSubstituto is null then
              vTrocaPrestSubstituto := vCodPrestadorSubst;
           else
              vTrocaPrestSubstituto := vTrocaPrestSubstituto || ' / ' || vCodPrestadorSubst;
           end if;
           --
           -- Select apenas para pegar o codigo do prestador para incluir na gravação da ocorrencia
           select cod_prestador
             into vCodPrestadorSubst
             from ts_odo.odo_prestador_servico
            where cod_prestador_ts = v_cod_prestador_ts_subst;
           --
           if vTrocaSubstituidoPor is null then
              vTrocaSubstituidoPor := vCodPrestadorSubst;
           else
              vTrocaSubstituidoPor := vTrocaSubstituidoPor || ' / ' || vCodPrestadorSubst;
           end if;
           else

             update ts_odo.odo_prestador_substituto
              set dt_atu                      = sysdate
                 ,cod_usuario_atu             = v_usuario
                 ,cod_prestador_ts_substituto = v_cod_prestador_ts_subst
            where cod_prestador_ts_excluido   = v_cod_prestador_ts
              and cod_operadora_excluido      = v_cod_operadora
              and cod_rede_excluido           = v_cod_rede;
        end if;
        --
      end if;
      --
      v_posicao := 41;
      --
    exception
      when dup_val_on_index then
        null;
      when others then
        p_cod_retorno := 1;
        p_msg_retorno := 'Prestador substituto e nulo ou nao habilitado na Operadora ' || v_cod_operadora || ' Rede ' || v_cod_rede;
        rollback;
        return;
    end;
    --
    v_posicao := 42;
    --
  end loop;
  --
  v_posicao := 34;
  --
  select ind_situacao
    into v_ind_situacao
    from odo_prestador_operadora
   where cod_prestador_ts = v_cod_prestador_ts
     and cod_operadora = v_cod_operadora;
  --
  if v_data_exclusao <= trunc(sysdate) then
    v_ind_situacao := 'E';
  end if;
  --
  update ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora
     set ind_situacao        = v_ind_situacao,
         cod_motivo_exclusao = v_cod_motivo_exclusao,
         dat_exclusao        = v_data_exclusao,
         txt_exclusao        = v_txt_exclusao,
         cod_usuario_atu     = v_usuario,
         dt_atu              = sysdate
   where cod_prestador_ts = v_cod_prestador_ts
     and cod_operadora    = v_cod_operadora;
  --
  if sql%rowcount = 0 then
    p_cod_retorno := 1;
    p_msg_retorno := 'Não foi possivel excluir o prestador da operadora: ' || v_cod_operadora;
    rollback;
    return;
  end if;
  --
  begin
    select ind_lista_negra
      into v_ind_lista_negra
      from odo_motivo_exclusao_prestador
     where cod_motivo_exclusao = v_cod_motivo_exclusao;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      v_ind_lista_negra := 'N';
  end;
  --
  -- Registra Ocorrencia
  if v_ind_lista_negra = 'S' then
     begin
       --
       vTxtObs := 'Exclusão (blacklist) realizada em ' || to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') || ' por ' || v_usuario || '. Operadora ' || v_cod_operadora;
       --
       insert into ts_odo.odo_ocorrencia_prestador
         (cod_prestador_ts,
          dat_ocorrencia,
          cod_operadora,
          cod_tipo_ocorrencia,
          txt_obs_ocorrencia,
          dt_atu,
          cod_usuario_atu)
       values
         (v_cod_prestador_ts,
          sysdate,
          v_cod_operadora,
          540,
          vTxtObs,
          sysdate,
          v_usuario);
     exception
       when others then
         p_cod_retorno := 1;
         p_msg_retorno := 'Erro ao inserir ocorrencia.';
         rollback;
         return;
    end;
    --
  else
    --
    begin
      --
      select o.nom_operadora
        into vNomeOperadora
        from ts.operadora o
       where o.cod_operadora = v_cod_operadora;
      --
      if vTrocaPrestSubstituto is null then
         vTxtObs := 'Exclusão realizada em ' || to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                                             || ' por ' || v_usuario || '. Operadora ' || vNomeOperadora
                                             || ' - Substituído por: ' || vSubstitutos;
      else
         vTxtObs := 'Exclusão realizada em ' || to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                                             || ' por ' || v_usuario || '. Operadora ' || vNomeOperadora
                                             || ' - Prestador Substituto: ' || vTrocaPrestSubstituto
                                             || ' - Substituído por:' || vTrocaSubstituidoPor;
      end if;
      --
      insert into ts_odo.odo_ocorrencia_prestador
        (cod_prestador_ts,
         dat_ocorrencia,
         cod_operadora,
         cod_tipo_ocorrencia,
         txt_obs_ocorrencia,
         dt_atu,
         cod_usuario_atu)
      values
        (v_cod_prestador_ts,
         sysdate,
         v_cod_operadora,
         517,
         vTxtObs,
         sysdate,
         v_usuario);
    exception
      when others then
        p_cod_retorno := 1;
        p_msg_retorno := 'Erro ao inserir ocorrencia.';
        rollback;
        return;
    end;
    --
  end if;
  --
  p_cod_retorno := 0;
  p_msg_retorno := ts_texto_mensagem('OK');
  --
  commit;
  --
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode = -2292 then
      p_msg_retorno := ts_texto_mensagem('ORA-2292');
      p_cod_retorno := 1;
      return;
    end if;
    --
    p_cod_retorno := 9;
    p_msg_retorno := 'odo_prs_registra_pedido_exclusao-' || v_posicao || ': ' || sqlerrm;
    Rollback;
    return;
    --
end;
```

Here date var:

```
v_data_exclusao          ts_odo.odo_prestador_operadora.dat_exclusao%type;
```

Here varchar variable

```
v_prazo_subs_ans         ts_odo.odo_controle_sistema.val_parametro%type;
```

I need to sum: `v_data_exclusao and v_prazo_subs_ans`

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column? I have also no idea what "sum date with varchar" is supposed to mean. **Edit** your question and add the table definition, some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: Ok, i'll edit my post and i'll post my stored proc code.

Comment: Now, the parameter value is: 60(60 days), so i need sum the date more 60 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I can only guess what you mean by summing of the date with a passed in varchar2... But my best guess is that you want to add a certain number of days (that are passed in as a varchar rather than a number for some reason) to a date that is also passed into a procedure.

```
DECLARE
  v_input VARCHAR2(1000) := '10';
  v_in_date DATE := trunc(SYSDATE);
  v_out_date DATE;
BEGIN
  --you might want to catch a VALUE_ERROR exception in case your input is not a number
  v_out_date := v_in_date + to_number(v_input);

  dbms_output.put_line('Date that is ' || v_input || ' days after ' || to_char(v_in_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') || ' is ' || to_char(v_out_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'));
END;
```

In response to your question in the comment. You can take a look at what happens if you add a number to a date that has a time on it. It just adds 1 day (24 hours) to the time of the date that you entered. If you wanted to get the new day (at midnight of that day) you would want to trunc your input date:

```
DECLARE
  v_date DATE := to_date('11/24/2015 12:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS');

BEGIN
  --add 1 day to the date passed in, so 24 hours is added to the date
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char((v_date + 1), 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'));
  --"11/25/2015 12:00:00"


  --if you want to only increment a day based on midnight of that day, just trunc your date
  v_date := trunc(v_date, 'DD'); --the date is truncated down to the day, ignoring time so: 11/25/2015 00:00:00
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char((v_date + 1), 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'));
--11/25/2015 00:00:00
END;
/
```

Comment: one question. If i have a date and time together and i sum this date with a number, like as: my_date + to_number(my_number_varchar), I have an increment of days or hours?

Comment: I made an edit. adding 1 to a date means you add 24 hours to the date. if you want midnight of the date you would want to either trunc the new date or trunc the original date before you add the number of days to it.